# PIP install MySQL-python on Windows fails in Python 64bit but succeeds if use 32bit

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm doing some legacy work with Python 2.7 on Windows, if use a virtual environment of Python-2.7 32-bit, and call "pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir MySQL-python" it completes all OK.

However, if use Python-2.7 in 64 bit, it fails with errors attached below. I noticed message "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include", which implies that the compiler was trying to include 32-bit files although this is a 64-bit Python environment.

Beside just the [unofficial wheels](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), could you please give me some pointers on how to fix this error and actually install this Python package?

For purpose of verification, I do need a fresh install with option --no-cache-dir. Thank you for your help.

**Error messege:**

```
(venv) D:\work\test_x64>where python
D:\work\test_x64\venv\Scripts\python.exe

(venv) D:\work\test_x64>python
Python 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

(venv) D:\work\test_x64>pip install MySQL-python
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-wheel-_dphfq'
       cwd: c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-install-q_zmcv\mysql-python\
  Complete output (103 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -ID:\work\test_x64\venv\include -ID:\work\test_x64\venv\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203) : warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T' : macro redefinition
          d:\work\test_x64\venv\include\pyconfig.h(347) : see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301) : warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H' : macro redefinition
          d:\work\test_x64\venv\include\pyconfig.h(687) : see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
  _mysql.c(287) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(317) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(470) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1168) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1274) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1466) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1468) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1504) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1506) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  _mysql.c(1532) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
  _mysql.c(2302) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\libs /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\PC\VS9.0\amd64 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:init_mysql build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_mysql.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.pyd.manifest
  _mysql.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_mysql' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.exp
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_error referenced in function _mysql_Exception
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_errno referenced in function _mysql_Exception
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_init referenced in function _mysql_server_init
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_end referenced in function _mysql_server_end
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_safe referenced in function _mysql_thread_safe
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_field_count referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_store_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_use_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_connect referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ssl_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_options referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_init referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_close referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_close
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_affected_rows referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_affected_rows
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_debug referenced in function _mysql_debug
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_dump_debug_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_autocommit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_commit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_commit
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_rollback referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_next_result referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_next_result
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_server_option referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_server_option
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_sqlstate referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_sqlstate
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_warning_count referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_warning_count
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_lengths referenced in function _mysql_row_to_tuple
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncat referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict_old
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_row referenced in function _mysql__fetch_row
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_rows referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_change_user referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_change_user
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_character_set_name referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_character_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_character_set
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_character_set_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_character_set_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_client_info referenced in function _mysql_get_client_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_host_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_proto_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_server_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_info
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_insert_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_kill referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_kill
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ping referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_ping
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_query referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_query
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_select_db referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_shutdown referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_stat referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_stat
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_sprintf referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_repr
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_data_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_data_seek
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_tell referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
  _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_free_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_dealloc
  LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup
  build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_mysql.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 56 unresolved externals
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for MySQL-python which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
    Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-record-ae_5vh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\include\site\python2.7\MySQL-python'
         cwd: c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-install-q_zmcv\mysql-python\
    Complete output (103 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -ID:\work\test_x64\venv\include -ID:\work\test_x64\venv\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203) : warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T' : macro redefinition
            d:\work\test_x64\venv\include\pyconfig.h(347) : see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301) : warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H' : macro redefinition
            d:\work\test_x64\venv\include\pyconfig.h(687) : see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
    _mysql.c(287) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(317) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(470) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1168) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1274) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1466) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1468) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1504) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1506) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    _mysql.c(1532) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
    _mysql.c(2302) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
    C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\libs /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\work\test_x64\venv\PC\VS9.0\amd64 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:init_mysql build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_mysql.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.pyd.manifest
    _mysql.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_mysql' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.exp
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_error referenced in function _mysql_Exception
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_errno referenced in function _mysql_Exception
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_init referenced in function _mysql_server_init
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_end referenced in function _mysql_server_end
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_safe referenced in function _mysql_thread_safe
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_field_count referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_store_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_use_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_connect referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ssl_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_options referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_init referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_close referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_close
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_affected_rows referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_affected_rows
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_debug referenced in function _mysql_debug
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_dump_debug_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_autocommit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_commit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_commit
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_rollback referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_next_result referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_next_result
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_server_option referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_server_option
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_sqlstate referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_sqlstate
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_warning_count referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_warning_count
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_lengths referenced in function _mysql_row_to_tuple
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncat referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict_old
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_row referenced in function _mysql__fetch_row
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_rows referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_change_user referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_change_user
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_character_set_name referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_character_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_character_set
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_character_set_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_character_set_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_client_info referenced in function _mysql_get_client_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_host_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_proto_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_server_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_info
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_insert_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_kill referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_kill
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ping referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_ping
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_query referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_query
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_select_db referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_shutdown referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_stat referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_stat
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_sprintf referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_repr
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_data_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_data_seek
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_tell referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
    _mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_free_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_dealloc
    LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup
    build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_mysql.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 56 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-install-q_zmcv\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-record-ae_5vh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\include\site\python2.7\MySQL-python' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'D:\work\test_x64\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) D:\work\test_x64>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing these,

```
pip install pymysql
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

or you can install the wheels from lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

You don't need to install visual studio build tools.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I resolved it by calling `pip install` command with `--global-option` to specify paths of include and lib files. See the example command below:

```
pip install MySQL-python ^
 --global-option=build_ext ^
 --global-option="-IC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" ^
 --global-option="-LC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt"
```

Notice that I've fully installed the 64-bit version of `MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2` at the customized location given in above example. See more details in self-posted answer to [another of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165600/python-2-7-64-bit-erroneously-refer-to-32-bit-x86-for-include-files/64178605#64178605).