# Why 64-bit `pip install MySQL-python` refers to `C:\Program Files (x86)\`?

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

On Windows, with a 64-bit Python environment, `pip install MySQL-python` consists of a call to `Visual C++ for Python` for compiling source code. By default, this call always gives wrong parameters telling the compiler to look into `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\` for include `.h` files and `.lib` files. `C:\Program Files (x86)\` contains 32-bit resources, not for 64-bit.

**As a workaround**, I fully installed **64-bit** version of `MySQL Connector C` in customized location given in example below, and called `pip install` command with `--global-option` to specify paths of include and lib files. See the example command:

```
pip install MySQL-python ^
 --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir ^
 --global-option=build_ext ^
 --global-option="-IC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" ^
 --global-option="-LC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" ^
 --verbose
```

**My question is:**

Why does `pip install MySQL-python` by default always look into the wrong directory of `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\` with 64-bit Python? Is this a bug, or did I miss any setting? Inputs will be highly appreciated.

Part of screen outputs relevant to compiler call:

```
...
  Created temporary directory: c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-us8ukn
    Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ...     Running command 'C:\my\test-pip\venv-
x64\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-2tppyl\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-2tppyl\\mysql-
python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' build_ext '-IC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include' '-
LC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt' install --record 
'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-us8ukn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-
managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\my\test-pip\venv-x64\include\site\python2.7\MySQL-python'
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for 
Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -
D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-
IC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\my\test-pip\venv-x64\include -IC:\my\test-
pip\venv-x64\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
...
```

As you see above, it tells the compiler to refer to `"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include"` even if the path doesn't exist. If interesting, please also refer to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165600/python-2-7-64-bit-erroneously-refer-to-32-bit-x86-for-include-files/) of mine.

Comment: Looks like it might have something to do with the `site.cfg` file -> https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/d34fac681487541e4be07e6978e0db233faf8252/site.cfg

Comment: @MarkMoretto, thank you for the hint. For this `site.cfg` file, if I want to modify it, where is its location on local system?

Comment: You could try importing it and printing MySQLdb.__path__[0] and then that folder might have it.  Otherwise, check your `Python\Lib\site-packages` folder for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such kind of issues earlier. Couple of things to check immediately,

1. Check the PATH environment variable. Ensure 64 bit python is in the PATH. Get rid of other python references from PATH variable.
2. Start -> Run. Type `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Python`. Usually Python will install scripts in this location. Ensure there are redundancies.

If above steps doesn't fix, I can add more steps based on above outcome. Good luck.